# Drawing line in notebook with Mathematica command

Tags: front-end, notebooks

I have a for loop that makes plots iteratively, in between the plots, I would like to draw a line in the notebook. Is there a command that is the equivalent of doing this:

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/InsertAHorizontalLineInANotebook.html

Comment: Any other method to divide my notebook up would be appreciated as well

Comment: Why not use `GraphicsColumn` and `Table` instead of `For` (and `Print`, I guess?)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's many ways to achieve something like this, but a start for programmatically creating a line to go across your notebook would be something like this:

```
CellPrint[
 Cell["", "Text", Editable -> False, Selectable -> False, 
  CellFrame -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0.5}}, ShowCellBracket -> False, 
  CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, 
  CellElementSpacings -> {"CellMinHeight" -> 1}, 
  CellFrameMargins -> 0, CellFrameColor -> RGBColor[0, 0, 1], 
  CellSize -> {Inherited, 3}]]
```

[image]

Of course the options can be edited, if you want it thicker, a different color, etc...

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

An alternative approach is to print the cells with graphics contents with a line at the bottom:

```
ClearAll[thickLineBelow]
thickLineBelow = CellPrint[ExpressionCell[#, "Output", CellFrame -> {{0, 0}, {3, 0}}, 
     CellFrameColor -> RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]] &;
```

You can wrap each graphics object you produce in the loop with `thickLineBelow`:

```
thickLineBelow /@ {Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, AspectRatio -> 1/4], 
   Row[Framed /@ {Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 100], 
      Plot[x Sin[x], {x, 0, 5 Pi}, ImageSize -> 200]}, Spacer[10]], 
   MatrixPlot[RandomReal[1, {5, 30}], ImageSize -> 300]};
```

[image]